# is it possible to apply an RC5 algorithm on an audio file in c++?

Tags: c++, encryption

is it possible to encrypt an audio file in c++ using rc5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) is an encryption library for C++.  It supports RC5 and RC6.  The fact that it is an audio file is of no importance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

I await the downvotes.

Comment: +1. It is the correct answer to this question :-) (I constrained myself from answering the same thing).

Comment: Lol - No down vote, but no upvote because others have more info :)

Comment: Right now it's +1/-1. I should probably delete this, but it's too much fun to leave it up.

Comment: can anyone help me out with an article as to how to go into the bits of an audio file in c? rather than just be able to play the file in c

Comment: @mekasperasky, the fact that it is an audio file makes no difference. fopen will do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. There is [a reference implementation in C](http://www.uqtr.ca/~delisle/Crypto/codes/rc5/rc5ref.c) available, and [a wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC5), that links to [a paper about the algorithm](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rivest-rc5.pdf) and how to implement it, along with other resources.